# Добавляем пустой view

Tags: java, android

Отображаю в своём активити данные, которые я получаю.
Добавил "пустой" view в activity_main.xml,  если данные не будут отображаться.

Код xml:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/empty_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/no_data_available"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

Теперь пробую прописать условие при которых в зависимости от отображения данных будут отображаться элементы:

```
private void initViews() {
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    topStoriesAdapter = new TopStoriesAdapter(models, this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(topStoriesAdapter);
    if (topStories.isEmpty()) {
        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        emptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        emptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Список отображается корректно, но если поменять местами в `if`'e `VISIBLE` с `GONE` местами, то будет отображаться только `TextView`.
Проблема в том, что к примеру если отключаю интернет, то данные которые я получаю с сервера не должны загружаться, но почему то `TextView` в этом случае не отображается, подскажите что я делаю не так.

Comment: так в чем вопрос то? что такое dataset ?

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei ну это я из примера вырвал если честно) но я так понимаю если я использую список для отображения данных, то это так раз и есть мой список не?

Comment: ну тогда все по сути верно, есть смысл проверить на null, 
так if (dataset != null && dataset.isEmpty()) { do something...}

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei не получается, список отображается, а вот если к примеру отключаю интернет и список отображаться не должен, то надпись всё таки не выходит, хотя по идее должна. Или если меняю местами visible и gone в if, то только textView отображается

Comment: а вот в чем дело, дело в том что данные вы уже получили в какой-то момент времени, а то что отключили инет это немного другое, вы просто переформулируйте вопрос, мол спрятать список когда пропал интернет, хотя кому это надо ? )

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei обновил вопрос.